# How well will XAMPP transfer to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, apache-http-server, windows-8, xampp

I'm in the middle of setting up XAMPP on my Windows 7 machine and I am wondering if it's worth my time doing it now if I plan on upgrading to Windows 8 Pro later this week.

Should I expect any issues or blocks with the Apache server? Will I have to make any configuration changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am Currently running the latest version of XAMPP on Windows 8 Pro without any issues. It performs on the desktop exactly the same as it did on Windows 7.

Keep in mind though that an upgrade to windows 8 will "uninstall" it by moving all its relevant files to a windows.old directory. So it may still be worth waiting until you have windows 8 installed.

Comment: Did you have to make any changes at all?

Comment: No. Just make the same considerations as in win 7 (Rights, UAC, etc.)